# JSON data is not getting populated in tree panel in extjs 4.2.x

Tags: extjs, extjs4, treepanel

With below configuration i am not able to populated json data in tree panel.

After loading store from server i am not able to see any records in console logs.

Is there any specific json structure need to be send from server?

Is there any configuration miss?

Below is the config i am using

**MODEL**

```
Ext.define('nsoapp.model.nso.Client', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.Field'
    ],

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'jsxid'
        },
        {
            name: 'name'
        },
        {
            name: 'type'
        },
        {
            name: 'countryId'
        },
        {
            name: 'contact'
        },
        {
            name: 'email'
        }
    ]
});
```

**STORE**

```
Ext.define('nsoapp.store.nso.Client', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

    requires: [
        'nsoapp.model.nso.Client',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            model: 'nsoapp.model.nso.Client',
            storeId: 'nso.Client',
            defaultRootProperty: 'record',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '/client/',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'populateClientRes'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

**TREE PANEL**

```
xtype: 'treepanel',
    flex: 1,
    margins: '0 0 3 0',
    itemId: 'treeClient',
    overlapHeader: false,
    title: 'Clients',
    titleCollapse: false,
    animate: true,
    displayField: 'name',
    rootVisible: false,
    viewConfig: {
        rootVisible: false
    }
```

In controller i am binding tree store to tree panel

```
var storeClient=this.getStore('nso.ordermanagement.clientcustomization.Client');
storeClient.load({
callback: function(records, operation, success) {
var treeClient=Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#treeClient")[0];
treeClient.bindStore(storeClient);
}
});
```

**JSON DATA**

```
{
  "populateClientRes":{
    "record":[
      {
        "name":"A_KPI",
        "type":"CLIENT",
        "jsxid":"14487361",
        "countryId":"484",
        "contact":"34434334",
        "email":"",
        "record":[
          {
            "name":"Products",
            "value":"1",
            "type":"PRODUCT"
          },
          {
            "name":"Stores",
            "value":"1",
            "type":"STORE"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"aCCStudyTest",
        "type":"CLIENT",
        "jsxid":"14425073",
        "countryId":"484",
        "contact":"1234567890",
        "email":"",
        "record":[
          {
            "name":"Products",
            "value":"1",
            "type":"PRODUCT"
          },
          {
            "name":"Stores",
            "value":"1",
            "type":"STORE"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: JSON response is wrong!

**Long answer**

You specify as root **populateClientRes** so all children (and children of children) must use this tag.

Standard JSON response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "children": [
        { 
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "Phil", 
            "leaf": true 
        },
        { 
            "id": 2, 
            "name": "Nico", 
            "expanded": true, 
            "children": [
                { 
                    "id": 3, 
                    "name": "Mitchell", 
                    "leaf": true 
                }
            ]},
        { 
            "id": 4, 
            "name": "Sue", 
            "loaded": true 
        }
    ]
}
```

In your case you have to replace **record** with **populateClientRes**:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "populateClientRes": [ 
        {
            "name":"A_KPI",
            "type":"CLIENT",
            "jsxid":"14487361",
            "countryId":"484",
            "contact":"34434334",
            "email":"",
            "populateClientRes": [
                {
                    ...         
                }, {
                    ...
                    populateClientRes: [{...},{...}]
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

**Important notes**

For all non-leaf nodes that do not have children (for example, Person with name Sue above), the server response MUST set the loaded property to true. Otherwise the proxy will attempt to load children for these nodes when they are expanded.

You find more information's [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/tree)

Comment: Thanks boss :). I thought keeping name as record record will help. but i have to give it as children only.

Comment: No problem ;) Another thing I don't understand is why you bind the store in such a 'uncommon' way... If you add *store:"Client"* to the treepanel config you are also fine. But as long as it works, it's fine =)

Comment: Because, if i bind store in config, tree panel automatically try to get data from server on render and i dont want that. Thats the reason i am binding this in controller. Is there any way by which i can bind store in config and uncheck rootVisible?

Comment: With *autoLoad:false* (store) and *rootVisible:false/true* (treepanel) it should work.